# Does any need to change API key while using GCM 3.0 Instance ID API?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, instanceid

Currently I am integrating `GCM 3.0` new registration process for push notification using `InstanceID API`.

Before that i am using `GCM 2.0 register()` method for push notifications and for that I have created project on Google developer console and created `Server API key` for sending push notification to Device

So now as i am migrating to `GCM 3.0` by referring this [link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start). while generating configuration file it asks two things:

1. Choose existing project or create project
2. Package name of application

By providing these two details it will Auto generate new `Server API key` but i have already created `API key` before that.

so is there is any need to change from old `API key` to new `API key` or stick to old `API key`?

Comment: Package name is not needed for server key. right?

Comment: yes it's not needed for server key

Comment: Then you can stick with the old key.

Comment: @Boss thanks. i will get back to u if face any issue while using old key

Comment: @Boss package name is required field

Comment: package name is for Android key, not server key, it requires a `name` and `ip` (optional)

Comment: If you go by the documentation (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#key) when you configure your project you should get a "new" API key. Provided you are using the existing project, it might be the same and in which case you can just cross-verify the same in your server implementation.

Comment: However, if you are creating a new project for GCM 3.0, you would most likely have a new API key which you would have to replace in your server implementation.

Comment: @KayAnn I have selected existing project for downloading config files but it is not allowing without mentioning existing project and then it is generating new API key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can use the old API key.

As the new process is just a New skin for building the API key and sender-id.